# How to prevent user from pasting incorrect value in a text box in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create a control that that let user enter hh:mm in a text box. 
However, I'm not able to get it working correctly when user tries to paste the invalid text.

Though the users are not able to type non alpha  numeric character. They are still able to paste it.

This is my host event that prevents user from typing any character other than *allowed characters*

```
@HostListener("keydown", ["$event"])
@HostListener("keyup", ["$event"])
onKeyDown(event: any) {
  let allowedCharacters = `^[0-9-:]*$`;
  const e = event as KeyboardEvent;
    if ([8, 9, 27, 13].indexOf(e.keyCode) !== -1 ||
        //Ctrl+A
        (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
        //Ctrl+C
        (e.keyCode === 67 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
        //Ctrl+V
        (e.keyCode === 86 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
        //Ctrl+X
        (e.keyCode === 88 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) ||
        //home, end, left, right
        (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode < 39)) {
        return;
    }
    if (!String(e.key).match(allowedCharacters)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

This is my ngModelChange event

```
 onModelChange(value: any): void {
   this.myTextBoxValue= value;
}
```

And this is my textbox:

```
<input type="text" [ngModel] = "myTextBoxValue" (ngModelChange)="onModelChange($event)"
```

Comment: why are you trying to intercept keystrokes instead of just filtering the value as it's received in onModelChange?

Comment: @bryan60, becasue I want the _invalid_ key strokes not even be "typeable"? I do not think we can achieve that with onModelChange.

Comment: You should give it a try the way I suggested. It will happen so fast that it will appear to have not happened at all.

Answer (score 3):

Trigger a paste event

```
<input type="text" [ngModel] = "myTextBoxValue" (paste)="onPaste($event)" (ngModelChange)="onModelChange($event)"
```

Component:

```
onPaste(e: any) { e.preventDefault()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your keydown method :

```
onKeyDown(event: any) {
   const e = event as KeyboardEvent;
   var charCode = e.keyCode;
   if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 58 )) {
      return false;
   }
      return true;
}
```

This only allow to enter numbers and `:` char. hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this so user is not able to paste values in the textbox.

```
<input (paste)="false" />
```